# dynamically changing text on a page using CKEditor 5 in django

Tags: python, django, ajax, ckeditor5

please tell me, is there a ready-made solution for Ckeditor - 5 to change the contents of the page without going to the admin panel, as well as without refreshing the page?

example:
[image]

in general, you can do this yourself using forms and ajax, for example, but why invent a bicycle if you already have one?